Limiting access to Google Earth Engine code
Is there a way to conceal specific lines of code in Google Earth Engine's code interface?
The Earth Engine script I'm working on will be available to the public but there are some lines (asset paths) that shouldn't be visualized by the users as they contain sensitive data. The data from this assets should be used in the script's execution, it's just the path's that can't show.

No.  Publicly accessible means publicly accessible.  You could attempt to obfuscate it with something like a module, but if the user can run it, they can (eventually) see the code.
The only way to make sure the user can't see the code is to host the code behind a server. The AppEngine examples (or Cloud Functions) show one way to do that, but it means all your EE logic has to be hidden on your sever (so you can't use EE Apps).

How would this obfuscation work?

You'd put some content in another module and require() that module into the main one.  But like I said, this doesn't do much to hide the content.  It's at best just a speed-bump.
